# Getting all entries from a database that start with letters using HTTP request

Tags: angularjs, json, http, get, http-headers

I am writing a simple filter function that sends a request and gets all entries that partially match the query. Desired behavior is if do a `GET` request `localhost:3000/employees?email=mai` I would like to receive all entries from a database starting with `mai`. Is there any way to construct an http requests for the desired behavior from a front-end part of the application? Perhaps some headers that tell the server that the search should not be strict? I have tryed googling it but failed. I am using `AngularJS` fro front-end and `json-server` as a back-end mock server

Answer (score 0):

Up to my understanding if you filter data in front End you will get only that data filtered which you are showing. In the other hand If you do this using Query(Back End) all the data get filtered in DB.